# Python/ Django- Internal Server Error after performing a soft reset

Tags: python, django, git

I recently made some changes to my Python/ Django project, and this caused one of the pages to display a 'Bad Gateway' message in the browser. I was unable to resolve this, so tried doing a 'soft reset' to the last working commit I had made. However, I am now getting an `Internal Server Error` when trying to view the website on the live server.

The error message doesn't give any more information than this... but when I view my project locally in the browser, it works as expected.

I've tried committing my local version, pushing it to the server, and then pulling it on the server again, but on the master branch on my local machine and on the server, I get a message telling that there's "nothing to commit, working directory clean".

How can I resolve this `Internal Server Error` to ensure that my site is accessible again?

Comment: Have you tried to use the django extensions? It has the runserver_plus and it gives more information to debug. Also it would be good check the ALLOWED_HOSTS variable...

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 'bad gateway', that means you're using something like Nginx or Apache to route requests to your app.

A Bad Gateway error means that Nginx (substitute Apache if appropriate, I'll just use nginx here) isn't getting a response from the app server - your `runserver` equivalent isn't serving the app, or the app is returning a 500 error.

The app server is usually served with gunicorn, uwsgi or sometimes just plain ol' runserver (but please don't do this in production!)

You can access your nginx logs at /var/log/nginx/error.log - it'll probably say `connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream`, with an IP address.

SSH to your server, run the virtualenv if you have one.  If gunicorn is running, stop it.

Do `which gunicorn` (again, substitute uwsgi if appropriate) to get the location, and run that manually:

`/etc/gunicorn/gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -w 1 myapplication.wsgi`

and note the error message.  You can also get this by doing runserver to see what's happening - if the app loads, then go to the website and see what the error message is in your terminal console.

It's probably a misconfiguration that's stopping the app from running - that's where you'll get your more detailed debug information.

Comment: When performing the `supervisorctl restart all` command after pushing my changes to the server, and pulling them on the server, I noticed that all of the servers 'stopped' correctly, but the 'gunicorn' one showed an error when the others all said 'started'... I can't remember exactly what the error was, but I tried running `supervirosrctl restart all` again, and they all stopped and started again correctly (including gunicorn)

Comment: Where do I find /var/log/nginx/error.log to access my nginx logs?

Comment: That's literally the filepath on your machine, unless you've customised your install.

Comment: on the server? Or on my local machine? When I try to view the site in the browser, the browser console doesn't show any output at all...

Comment: As I said in the answer, SSH into your machine and start gunicorn manually to see what it's doing (if anything) when it comes in.   Once you're SSH'd in, then navigate to that filepath to see your error log.

Comment: I am SSH'd into my server. I don't know if I have a `virtualenv`... Running `which gunicorn` displays the output: `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn`. When I run `/etc/gunicorn/gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -w 1 myapplication.wsgi`, (obviously using the name of my application, rather than 'myapplication'), I get a message saying: `[2016-12-09 15:22:07 +0000] [74] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.5.0`, then `[2016-12-09 15:22:07 +0000] [74] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)`, then `[2016-12-09 15:22:07 +0000] [74] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.`... It does this a few times before displaying:

Comment: `[2016-12-09 15:22:12 +0000] [74] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8000)`

Comment: Ok, so gunicorn's still running then.  You need to stop it first, with supervisorctl.

Comment: Just running `supervisorctl` gives the output: `-ssh: supervisorctl: not found` when running it from SERVER>... is there a command I need to run with it, like `supervisorctl stop all`?

Comment: There's a limited amount I can do with this tbh, this is some pretty basic server admin.   http://supervisord.org/running.html Have a look at that, and maybe the digitalocean tutorials about setting up django with supervisord.  You might need sudo to access supervisorctl depending how it's been set up.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting this issue... given that this is exactly how I have pushed changes to the server in the past, and it has always worked after running `git pull origin master` on the server, and then doing `supervisorctl restart all`... I followed exactly the same process this time, but keep getting the 'Internal Server Error'...

Comment: did you manage to sort out? I do not think I have updated the project and all of a sudden getting 'Internal Server Error' message. Not sure where to start debugging the problem.